# Get time format of system calendar

Tags: c#

I want to know whether the time format of system clock is 12 hour based or 24 hour based in C#. DateTime can be converted to 12/42 hour format using the formats like hh:mm:ss and HH:mm etc but I want to know which format is being used by system clock. Any suggestion?

Comment: That's not how you do it. You ask the system to format the time in the user's preferred format. You don't to know whether that is 12 or 24 hour.

Comment: Means there is no way to know the format of system clock?

Comment: The approach could be like, 

1. Get System.DateTime.Now
2. Grab the Hour part
3. If it is less than 12, and there is no AM/PM, it is in 12 hour mode.

Comment: My point is that you should not be concerned with 12 or 24 hour format. That detail is too low level. You just want a time to be formatted to the user's preferences. Let the framework handle the details.

Comment: @David Heffernan: That is my point. I want to show the time exactly as user has specified in the calendar settings. Different users can have different formats, so adjusting the format for all is not possible in this way.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan: The AM/PM part that is displayed in the clock can be customized too. If that bit of information is stripped off then there is no way to tell whether time is in 12 or 24 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current thread culture info:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat
```

Edit:
Clarification, hour formats hh/HH indicate 12/24 hour setting. Look for DateTimeFormat properties like ShortTimePattern and LongTimePattern.

Comment: This tells about the format that is specified for current culture. A user can have different format than specified in the culture in calendar settings.

Comment: In DateTimeFormat look for properties like ShortTimePattern and LongTimePattern, when format for hours is HH it means that 24 hour format is set, if format for hours is hh then calendar settings are set for 12 hour format.

Comment: User can have different format than what is defined in the current culture.

Comment: @NadeemAkhtar Can you explain how that is possible

Comment: @NadeemAkhtar If user changes time format in windows calendar settings then current culture property will reflect that change, provided you didnt set culture arbitrally. Maybe we are talking about different settings.

Comment: @Wojtek: Currently my culture is of United States and short time format is h:mm tt and long time format is HH:mm:ss. But I can change the time format by going into the Regional and Language and then Customize Format. Here I can set the short time to hh:mm and similarly to long time as HH:mm:ss.

Comment: @NadeemAkhtar Yes, user can set long and short time formats independently. Im not aware of different system time format settings. If that information is needed for time presentation then you can use both settings depending on format in which you are presenting time, if more important business rule is based on time format you will have to make some assumptions (eg. short time format determines rule outcome).

Comment: @NadeemAkhtar Can't you see that you are asking for the impossible? You want some form of magic. In the scenario you describe, where the user chooses 12 hour for short, and 24 hour for long, you want a method that tells you whether the user prefers 12 or 24 hour?! You are thinking about this entirely the wrong way. You simply don't care about that detail. Just format the time using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat`. End of story.